# How to use a custom deleter with a shared pointer

Tags: c++, sdl, shared-ptr

How do can I create a shared pointer to a SDL_Texture* struct. I have written a custom deleter "functor" as follows...

```
struct ResourceDeleter {
    void operator()(SDL_Texture *t) const {
        if (t != nullptr) {
            SDL_DestroyTexture(t);
            t = nullptr;
        }
    }
};
```

This used to work fine with unique_ptr

```
std::unique_ptr<SDL_Texture, ResourceDeleter>
createTexture(SDL_Renderer *renderer, Uint32 format, int access, int w, int h) {
    return std::unique_ptr<SDL_Texture, ResourceDeleter>(
            SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, format, access,
                              w, h),
            ResourceDeleter());
}
```

but I don't know how to integrate this with a shared_ptr.

SDL2-https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL

Comment: What exactly is the problem you encountered? It works pretty much the same with `std::shared_ptr` except that it doesn't take the deleter type as template argument.

Comment: Have you considered to wrap that c-style api in a class to apply RAII?

Comment: `t = NULL;` doesn't do anything useful - `t` is passed by value.

Comment: about  `t = nullptr;` maybe I don't understand the "Use After Free vulnerabilities"

Answer (score 2):

Like `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` has a constructor that takes the custom deleter. [See the documentation.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)

Below example is from the link:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
 
struct Foo {
    int id{0};
    Foo(int i = 0) : id{i} { std::cout << "Foo::Foo(" << i <<  ")\n"; }
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "Foo::~Foo(), id=" << id << '\n'; }
};
 
struct D {
    void operator()(Foo* p) const {
        std::cout << "Call delete from function object. Foo::id=" << p->id << '\n';
        delete p;
    }
};
 
int main()
{
    std::cout << "3) constructor with object and deleter\n";
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> sh4(new Foo{11}, D());
}
```