# Allocating on heap and then use shared pointer, how to free the data

Tags: c++

I have the following scenario.
I have a allocated a chunk of data using new, then assigned the block of data to a smart pointer in the class DNA_ImageBlob, how do I free T*blob data ?

```
template <class T>
void DNA_ImageBlob<T>::Reset(int h, int w, int c)
{
    SetWidth(w);
    SetHeight(h);
    SetDepth(c);
    T *blob = alocData(h, w, c);
    data_ = std::make_shared<T>(blob);
    compressed_ = false;
}

template <class T>
T *DNA_ImageBlob<T>::alocData(unsigned int h, unsigned int w, unsigned int d)
{
    if (w * h * d == 0)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    T *blob = new T[w * h * d];
    return blob;
}
```

and the usage of that class is in :

```
DNA_Mask::DNA_Mask(int id, int xSize, int ySize, int zSize)
        : DNA_BinaryImageBlob(xSize, ySize, zSize)
    {
        mID = id;
        height_ = xSize;
        width_ = ySize;
        depth_ = zSize;
        data_ = std::shared_ptr<BinaryType>(this->alocData(height_, width_, depth_));
```

Comment: You don't. The smart pointer does it for you. That's the whole point of using smart pointers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a custom deleter with a shared pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71507638/how-to-use-a-custom-deleter-with-a-shared-pointer)

Comment: @VLL How is that answer related to my piece of code, can you explain more?

Comment: Do you really need a shared_ptr though? I would keep one blob per data item, make the data a std::vector and let RAII take care of the rest. Then you can just return a const& to the vector data if client code needs access. So DNA_Image blob is not a class used to allocate data, it really will represent a blob of data

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii, try to understand this concept it is core of writing resource/memory leak free C++. And works great when you leave scopes of functions at multiple places (or use exceptions)

Comment: @PepijnKramer can you answer with pseudo code please ? That's what I really want to do, but I'm a beginner :)

Comment: If you want to use a shared pointer, you *must* use a custom deleter. That's because `std::shared_ptr` doesn't have an "array" overload, so it only does plain `delete` when you need `delete[]`. Mismatching news and deletes leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: And to emphasize the point of @PepijnKramer, do you *really* need a shared pointer? Do you even need `new[]` and `delete[]` and pointers? Why not use a `std::vector<T>`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Can you elabratoe an answer with a custom deleter ?

Comment: I made an example for you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can you show an example please?

Comment: [RAII guideline](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r1-manage-resources-automatically-using-resource-handles-and-raii-resource-acquisition-is-initialization), [avoid-new-and-delete-outside-resource-management-functions](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es60-avoid-new-and-delete-outside-resource-management-functions). In general avoid the use of new/delete, look for containers from the standard library, or use std::make_unique (std::shared_ptr has its own issues with respect to circular references, so must designed up front )

Comment: In modern C++ (>=03), if you need a list-like container your first choice should be `std::vector<>`. It's also your second and third. The only reason to be allocating arrays is a narrow set of compatibility use cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example, if you have questions just ask.

```
#include <vector> 
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

// Blob is a RAII class, meaning its destructor will 
// cleanup all resources it owns (in this case memory held by vector)
class Blob
{
public:
    Blob(std::size_t width, std::size_t depth, std::size_t height) :
        m_blob_data(width * depth * height, 0) // allocates memory and sets it to 0. (last parameter is optional)
    {
    }

    // provide read only access to data
    const auto& get_data() const noexcept
    {
        return m_blob_data;
    }

    ~Blob() = default; 

private:
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> m_blob_data; // when destructor is called, vector gets destructed which will free memory
};

int main()
{
    // start a scope (yes this has meaning in C++, and is important with respect to RAII)
    {
        Blob blob{ 2,2,2 };
        std::cout << blob.get_data().size() << "\n"; // 2*2*2 = 8 items.
    } // blob goes out of scope here, so from here on memory is freed.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can I replace alocData() with your own version ?

Comment: Not directly this is a different concept, it will not require alocData at all. The client that called allocData should now use get_data(). Just make sure your Blob lives long enough and isn't deleted before the caller is done with the data. Maybe you just need to learn a bit more C++? Here is a bit more on RAII, https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/destructors/ but I think it won't hurt you to go over the full course.

Comment: So maybe not the direct answers you where looking for, but if you want to learn C++. You can make some steps today :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem is to refactor the code to your approach, can you give some hints inside the answer ?

Comment: for example that line how can I replace it with your approach: `data_ = std::shared_ptr<BinaryType>(this->alocData(height_, width_, depth_));
`

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the rest of your code.  It all depends on lifetimes and wetherer you can do with a Blob still need a std::shared_ptr<Blob>. But this is something you have to figure out on your own.  (probably Blob needs to be templated too, so it can hold other things then a std::uint8_t). If you are not multithreading try to come up with a design that doesnt need shared_ptr but relies on well defined lifetimes. (Otherwise there is still unique_pointer and move, but that's a whole different story)

Comment: Do you think replacing shared_ptr, to unique ptr is a better approach

Comment: As said it all depends on the overall design what is best. A unique_ptr models the fact that there is only one owner at a time for the data. As said it is best if you learn a bit more about those concepts (like ownership). Then update your design with this lifecycles and ownserships in mind and ony then start refactoring. For now just put the `delete` in the correct place. What I mostly wanted to show you that "C++", standard library containers, RAII have their nicely interlocking way of doing things that can avoid a lot of (memory related) bugs

Comment: The problem is with your approach, I need to write a lot of modifications... do you have an easier approach, like the deleter method ? –

Comment: Best fixes are not always the easiest. And I am not trying to fix your code, I am trying to learn you something :)

Comment: What do you mean by just put delete in the correct place?

Comment: There is code that calls allocate_data() which returns a T*, the calling code will need to delete this. Replacing that line with a std::make_unique and returning a unique_ptr might be the quickest fix. And that's what I will leave you with.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<T> blob = std::make_unique<T>[w * h * d];`  is that what you mean ? The syntax is wrong :(

Comment: @AhmedSaleh `auto blob = std::make_unique<T[]>(w * h * d);`

Comment: Yes the latter one you are making an instance of an array of T, not a single one. The distinction is important. When the unique_ptr goes out of scope it will delete the memory for you (using a delete[] call)